# Uiautomatorviewer Premature end of file

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I have been using uiautomatorViewer for quite a while and today for the first time i got an error :

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:/tmp/uiautomatorviewer_2911009098837440934/dump_6467398984523677157.uix;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:391)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1404)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1034)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
>       at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
>       at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:328)
>       at com.android.uiautomator.tree.UiHierarchyXmlLoader.parseXml(UiHierarchyXmlLoader.java:128)
>       at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorModel.(UiAutomatorModel.java:42)
>       at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorHelper.takeSnapshot(UiAutomatorHelper.java:142)
>       at com.android.uiautomator.actions.ScreenshotAction$1.run(ScreenshotAction.java:85)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   null rootnode after parsing.

I always get this error when i go to this page and i have no idea why, any ideas?

Comment: It is due to unrecognized characters on the page, i don't think there is anything to do about it except waiting for a patch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI: I filed a [bug against the android team](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62906).
They recently merged a fix for android L: it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note to anyone else finding this bug, it seems that this issue was accepted by an Android team member on February 25, 2014: [Link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62906). So, hopefully it will be fixed in a update soon.